# How to create on time login screen using html/php for android WebView

Tags: php, html, android-studio, webview

I'm a newbie in Android. I'm making an app for which i require login/registration screen. But I'm opting Hybrid development for this. But like Android `SharedPreferences`, I want one time login screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The question might be too broad, also can you please show some research effort?